# How to locate editext in linear layout programmatically?

Tags: android

[image: Original image]

[image: edited image]

How to locate `edittext` nearby `TextView`("Enter the number of linedata")??
Here is my code..Is it possible to do this inside `LinearLayout`

```
public class Ybus_Activity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_ybus);
final LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
final LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.android_main_layout);
TextView getData=new TextView(this);
getData.setText("Enter the number of LineData : ");
getData.setId(5);
getData.setLayoutParams(params);
main.addView(getData);
final EditText edText = new EditText(this);
edText.setId(3);
edText.setLayoutParams(params);
edText .setWidth(100);
edText .setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
edText .setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
edText .setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance());
edText .setMaxLines(1);
main.addView(edText );
Button bt = new Button(this);
bt.setText("Click to enter Linedata");
bt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
main.addView(bt);
final TextView text = new TextView(this);
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{ 
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        String ed=edText.getText().toString(); 
        int i = 0;
        try{
          i =Integer.parseInt(ed);
         //setting value here
          text.setText(i+"");
         //or you can do like this
         //text.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
          text.setText("Value at TextView is not a valid integer");
        }
    }
});
main.addView(text);
 }
}
```

Comment: @Raghunandan How bro..?I'm new to Android..

Comment: Sorry i misread the question. you want to move the view next to textview programatically?

Comment: how to move edittext near to text view

Comment: @Raghunandan yes bro..i need to move the edittext near to text view

Comment: why don't you design a layout the way you want using a a xml layout

Comment: @Raghunandan no bro...I wanna use for loop to get multiple textview dynamically...

Comment: in that case using a listview is an option since it is dynamic items can be added and deleted accordingly

Comment: @Raghunandan bro but i need to do this in linear layout...any idea??

Comment: i would not recommend creating textview in for loop use a lsitview or have a single textview and append values to it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48060/discussion-between-gkn06-and-raghunandan)

Answer (score 2):

create a relative layout instead of a linear layout.Try something like this

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams pSS = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
                            ,
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
                    pSS.addRule(RelativeLayout.Right, id of the textview);
                    pSS.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

                    edText .setLayoutParams(pSS);
```

Comment: Why RelativeLayout??Cant i do this in linear layout

Comment: yup u can do it in Linear Layout as well but always prefer to set your layouts in a relative fashion

Comment: do you have any idea in doing this by linear layout

Comment: then set the orientation of the linear layout to horizontal

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
final LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.android_main_layout);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setLayoutParams( new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);


    TextView getData=new TextView(this);
    getData.setText("Enter the number of LineData : ");
    getData.setId(5);
    getData.setLayoutParams(params);
    layout.addView(getData);
    final EditText edText = new EditText(this);
    edText.setId(3);
    edText.setLayoutParams(params);
    edText .setWidth(100);
    edText .setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
    edText .setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    edText .setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance());
    edText .setMaxLines(1);
    layout.addView(edText );
    Button bt = new Button(this);
    bt.setText("Click to enter Linedata");
    bt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    main.addView(layout);
    main.addView(bt);
    final TextView text = new TextView(this);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    { 
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            String ed=edText.getText().toString(); 
            int i = 0;
            try{
              i =Integer.parseInt(ed);
             //setting value here
              text.setText(i+"");
             //or you can do like this
             //text.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
              text.setText("Value at TextView is not a valid integer");
            }
        }
    });
    main.addView(text);
```